# How to select data across multiple MySQL tables with same ID

Tags: mysql

I had create two table (Table A and Table B) and try using INNER JOIN both table but the result will be in different row even the ID is same.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table A INNER JOIN Table B ON Table A.ID = Table B.ID";
```

Is there any mysql select to extract all the value with same ID in one row as shown in 'Result' table?
Code:

```
$sql = 
  "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM1), GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM2) 
   FROM Table A INNER JOIN Table B 
   ON Table A.ID = Table B.ID 
   WHERE Table A.ID = Table B.ID ";
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zviw3.png)

Comment: Read up  group_concat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: yes, you can do with group_concat().

Comment: I had try using group_concat, however the result only show me ID=1 result

Comment: $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM1), GROUP_CONCAT(ITEM2) FROM Table A INNER JOIN Table B ON Table A.ID = Table B.ID WHERE Table A.ID = Table B.ID ";

Answer (score 1):

You must `group by id, type` and use [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) only for the `item` columns.
From your sample data it seems like one of `item1` or `item2` in each row is `null`.
If this is the case then:

```
select
  a.id, a.type,
  group_concat(coalesce(b.item1, b.item2) order by b.sub_id) item
from tablea a inner join tableb b
on b.id = a.id
group by a.id, a.type
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmweL5xquMsDwgPgrdMx54/4).
If they can be both `null` or both not `null`:

```
select
  a.id, a.type,
  group_concat(concat_ws(',', item1, item2) order by b.sub_id) item
from tablea a inner join tableb b
on b.id = a.id
group by a.id, a.type
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dmweL5xquMsDwgPgrdMx54/5).
Results:

```
| id  | type      | item                        |
| --- | --------- | --------------------------- |
| 1   | FRUIT     | BANANA,PINEAPPLE,WATERMELON |
| 2   | VEGETABLE | SPINACH,CARROT              |
| 3   | MEAT      | CHICKEN                     |
```